# Implementing a lock

Tags: c++, multithreading, locking

I'm trying to understand how locks work.

Let's say I want to implement a really simple lock in C++

```
class Resource{
    public:
    bool lock();
    void unlock();
    ... methods to change/read the Resource ...

    private:
    bool isLocked;
}
```

The user of the Resource calls `lock()`, and if `isLocked` is true, then `lock()` returns false, and the user of the Resource has to either wait, or do something else. If `isLocked` is false, then `lock()` sets `isLocked` to true, and returns true. Then the caller can do whatever he wants to the resource. He calls `unlock()` on the resource afterwards to set `isLocked` to false.

However, what if two users of the resource call `lock()` at precisely the same time? Does this situation rarely happen? I think more formally, this involves making the `lock()` operation "atomic", though I'm not precisely sure what that word means.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Atomic" means that the operation can't be interrupted.  That is, you can be sure that the semantics of that operation are the same regardless of the behaviour of other threads/processes.  You're right that something in your `lock()` call will likely have to be atomic.  Most architectures provide some helpful instructions with guaranteed atomic behaviour - you might also find some libraries built on those operations to give you more flexibility at the higher layer you're programming at.

Comment: Would atomicity be a characteristic of the `lock()` method as a whole, or particular statements in the `lock()` method? The first option seems easier to work with.

Comment: Well that's really up to your implementation, I guess.  At the really fundamental level, it's only single machine instructions that are atomic.  You can extend that up through other layers by writing appropriate code, though.

Answer (score 6):

With the old, standard C++, you cannot implement your own lock, since the lock variable itself is in a data race.

C++11 and C11 add *atomic* variables, which you can use for precisely this purpose; e.g. in C++:

```
#include <atomic>

std::atomic<bool> isLocked;

bool lock() { return !isLocked.exchange(true); }

void unlock() { isLocked = false; }
```

The key here are the atomic exchange and the (implicit) atomic store, which generate special hardware instructions and are always race-free, and which you cannot "fake" with ordinary variables.

Answer (score 1):

It's not at all rare.  It's called a race condition, and is the cause of many (if not most) bugs in multithreaded code.

The C++ standard doesn't really have any concept of threads/atomicity and so on,<sup>1</sup> so you'll need to rely on synchronisation primitives offered by your OS (or perhaps via Boost).

---

<sub>1. This is no longer true with C++11.</sub>